# Phpstan Class_parent not found

Tags: oxid, phpstan

I am trying to get static PHP code analysis to work on my OXID 6 eshop.

I am, however, hitting a brick wall when it comes to this:

When I run `vendor/bin/phpstan analyse --configuration phpstan.neon source/modules/myvendor/mymodule` I always get errors like `Class  mynamespace\Article_parent not found`.

This is probably because in Oxid, the eshop classes are not directly overwritten, but instead declared like this

```
<?php
namespace mynamespace;

class Article extends Article_parent
{
...
```

and in a `metadata.php` the overwritten class is defined:

```
'extend' => [
        \OxidEsales\Eshop\Application\Model\Article::class => \mynamespace\Article::class,
    ],
```

Phpstan does not seem to be able to resolve this, I've tried many different configuration files, like this one

```
parameters:
    level: max
    inferPrivatePropertyTypeFromConstructor: true
    autoload_files:
        - vendor/oxid-esales/oxideshop-ce/source/oxfunctions.php
        - vendor/oxid-esales/oxideshop-ce/source/overridablefunctions.php
```

or this one

```
parameters:
    level: 7
    autoload_files:
    - vendor/oxid-esales/testing-library/base.php
    - vendor/oxid-esales/oxideshop-ce/source/oxfunctions.php
    - vendor/autoload.php
```

but to no avail.
How can I get phpstan to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\mynamespace\Article_parent` class does not exist and will be created at runtime as an alias. This is because it depends on your configuration / other modules installed where this alias points to.

My colleague Alfred Bez created the `oxid-dump-autoload` tool, what will dump out the module chain based on your current configuration and setup, so that PHPStan / Psalm can find the classes:

https://github.com/alfredbez/oxid-dump-autoload

Hope I could help

Comment: Just stumbled upon this question, happy to answer any questions about that tool (I'm the author)

Answer (score 2):

Please upgrade to the latest PHPStan version 0.12.33.

In version 0.12.26 a lot has been reworked that's described in [this article](https://phpstan.org/blog/zero-config-analysis-with-static-reflection). The main takeaway is that you should no longer get "class not found" for classes that clearly exist without any need for additional configuration.

Also, autoload_files has been deprecated. Please follow [Discovering Symbols](https://phpstan.org/user-guide/discovering-symbols) guide to see what to do instead (you can most likely just delete this section from your configuration).

Comment: Also, this part (custom autoloader) might apply to you: https://phpstan.org/user-guide/discovering-symbols#custom-autoloader